# How could i get numbers instead of Nan?

Tags: javascript

I've been doing some challenge to create Fibonacci numbers generator,and got stack. It seemed like i have a solution, but those NaN's is the last problem i cant't deal with.

```
function fibonacciGenerator (n) {

   var output = [];

 if( n === 2 ){
       output.push(0,1);
   }
  else if( n === 1 ){
       output.push(0);
       } 

else{
output = [0,1];
 while( n > output.length){
                    
         output.push((output[output.length - 2]) + (output[output.lenght - 1]));
     }
  
 }
     
   
     
   return output
   
   
  
}
```

So when i use function with n=3 and higher, it pushes sum of the two last numbers of output array into that array, till n< output.length. And everything works, loop stops when n=output.lenght, but i got back NaN's, not numbers. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: it might be because there's a typo in your code. `output.lenght` should be `output.length`

Comment: You misspelled length in the push in the while loop

Comment: Yeah, typo was a problem) Thanks gyus, that cost me a day) I thought that function didn't want to return numbers as numbers, and returns it as a text, thats why + didnt work. And i spend few hours to find out how make this text numbers again) For sure i din't find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Mispelled length as lenght here

```
while( n > output.length){
                    
         output.push((output[output.length - 2]) + (output[output.lenght - 1]));
     }
  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function fibonacciGenerator(n) {

    var output = [];

    if (n === 2) {
        output.push(0, 1);
    }
    else if (n === 1) {
        output.push(0);
    }

    else {
        output = [0, 1];
        while (n > output.length) {
            // problem was here output.length was misspelld
            output.push((output[output.length - 2]) + (output[output.length - 1]));
        }

    }
    return output
}

console.log(fibonacciGenerator(5))
```